# Using copy-item in powershell to transfer file on a shared drive

Tags: powershell, robocopy, copy-item

I have an excel file that is used to perform certain operations on the database & that sheet needs to be copied right when the update is made. I have the script that does the update on the database but before that, I'm using the Copy-Item command to save the copy of the source excel file with a new name. But I'm getting a generic error like:

```
"Error/ getting/reading excel file \\shared\\documents\\myData.xlsx"
```

Is that a permission issue or am I having an incorrect syntax. Or should I use robocopy command in powershell? Here's the chunk of powershell code that I have written so far:

```
#source file location
$fileLocation = "\\shared\documents\myData.xlsx"
#getting current date
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
#destination location
$backUpLocation = "\\shared\backup\myData_" + $currentDate + ".xlsx"
#copying file 
Copy-Item $fileLocation $backUpLocation
```

Any better solution is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Too many backslashes. A UNC path only **starts** with two backslashes, the rest of the path use only one directory separator. Also you missed the `$` on `currentDate` when you create the path for the backup location

Comment: Thanks, Theo, I rectified my source code as well but it is still giving me the same error message.

Comment: Did you check the file is actually in that location? Do you have permission to go there? Is the file opened in excel at the time of copy? (P.s, the error message doesn't look like it comes from PowerShell. Is that the exact full error message or is there more ?)

Comment: That's the exact full message. I am able to open the file make edits & save them and also it allows me to copy directly. In the Catch block, I'm doing $_.Exception to catch the errors.

Comment: Is your code in a module? If so, try Import-Module with the `-Force` switch, or close powershell and start fresh. Also, are the file paths correct? I see `\\shared\restofoath`, but  does it start with the name or ip of the server where the share is?

Comment: It's just a single script file that's doing everything. Although I did add -Force just now in the copy-item command but no success. If I comment out the copy-item command the updates are happening on the DB and everything is working fine.

Comment: Add something like `if (!(Test-Path $fileLocation)) { throw "bad path" }` before the copy. Also take out your try/catch so you can see the real exception. `Copy-Item` isn't going to say "Excel File"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot! There was a silly mistake a file name cannot have ':' while the $currDate I was fetching is having a colon that's breaking. Copy-Item works best as it also allows renaming the file in the single command itself.